# SetEnvIf Host is not working for subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, magento, environment-variables, magento-1.9, subdomain

In my magento .htaccess file SetEnvIf Host is not working for subdomain, But it is working for domain

> **WORKING**

```
SetEnvIf Host www\.domain\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain_com 
SetEnvIf Host www\.domain\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^domain\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain_com
SetEnvIf Host ^domain\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

> **NOT WORKING**

```
SetEnvIf Host www\.sub\.domain\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain_com 
SetEnvIf Host www\.sub\.domain\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^sub\.domain\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain_com
SetEnvIf Host ^sub\.domain\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

Why is it so??? Is there any problem in my code? `mod_env is enabled`

My magento version is 1.9. Can any one please help me?

Comment: But even if I remove the first part, it is not working.

Comment: It is `domain.com/public_html/sub` Magento installation is under Public_html, ie root folder.

Comment: Then you need to place this in `public_html/sub/.htaccess`

Comment: So I need to create this htaccess file in sub-domain folder? But this sub-domain is picking up .htacces file from root folder, I tried to make a redirection, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: However I did as you said, but didn't work.. :(

Comment: Did you find a solution Hakkim? I have the same problem: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87107/sub-domain-stores-on-local-dev-server

Comment: @JoePalaca No, actually it is document root problem of my control panel, i was using direct admin, there I can't add subdomain for magento, so I moved my sites into cpanel, now it is working fine...

Answer (score 1):

Below code is working for me:

```
SetEnvIf Host ^php\.stagebox\.in MAGE_RUN_CODE=base 

SetEnvIf Host ^php\.stagebox\.in MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website

SetEnvIf Host ^phpnoida\.testfire\.in MAGE_RUN_CODE=basestd 

SetEnvIf Host ^phpnoida\.testfire\.in MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```